# Appication hangs when switching to Web View in Selendroid

Tags: selendroid

I am trying to test Hybrid App with Selendroid. When I am switching to Web View with
`driver.switchTo().window("WEBVIEW");`
it does not give any error on switching , however , my application hangs and do not open any web page.
What could be the problem?

Comment: When run manually, pages in webview are getting open.

Comment: Could you do try this. 
String nr =   driver.getWindowHandles().toString();
System.out.print(nr);
There might be an issue that the app has multiple webviews. Then you need to switch a specific webview.  driver.switchTo().window("WEBVIEW_0"); Example

Comment: @Madis Kangro : Yes , there are 2 WEBVIEWS :[NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_1, WEBVIEW_0]   I think I would require developer's help to switch to desired view to get the selendroid working.

Comment: Try either one of these 2. driver.switchTo().window("WEBVIEW_0") or driver.switchTo().window("WEBVIEW_1")

Comment: @Madis Kangro : Thanks now application is proceeding further and opening a page. But now selendroid is not able to find out the element I am trying to search with : driver.findElement(By.id("input_firstname")).sendKeys("first_name");

Comment: What does the selendroid inspector say.

Comment: It Says : org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Element was not found.                                                                                                            Driver info: io.selendroid.client.SelendroidDriver
Capabilities [{aut=<some_base_package>, automationName=selendroid, browserName=selendroid, platformName=android, platform=ANY}]
Session ID: e2062b17-5ee9-5ecc-5cd5-5d5fbd6b901f
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=first_name}

Comment: I'll be honest. I can't help you with that anymore. I don't have access to the app your testing so I dont have any clue if id selector is correct etc. You can try with to check if the element is there, at that moment. http://localhost:4444/inspector/  Also upvote my comment for other viewers incase they run also in the same problem

Comment: @Madis : On checking further, I observed that , WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(boolean); was not set. I made it to true and now able to find the elements of web page loading in webview of app. However I am facing strange issue for which I would create new question. Thank you for help.